# Batch Script / CMD [ open two different links both in different google chrome profiles ]

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to open two different links both in different google chrome profiles using the same batch script file.

eg.: `https://www.youtube.com` in profile no 1 & `https://skribbl.io` in profile no 2

So I can watch YouTube in the first profile and play games in the second profile.

I have 2 screens just need the batch script to start both links.

And yes I play a lot skribbl.io while watching YouTube videos on my other screen !

Comment: I think you mean google chrome profiles and not google profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Any One With The Same Problem . . .

This Code Below Work !

Just be sure to change the Google Installation Location according to your computer. And change the link to anything you want to use. Also don't forget to set the correct Google Profile profile name . . .

```
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.anycustomlink.com --profile-directory="Profile_name"
```

The Code Below Will Open YouTube With The Third Google Chrome Profile !

```
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.youtube.com --profile-directory="Profile 3"
```

Thanks A Lot Again @ArraffaFile

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER:** If i understood, you want to open a link on chrome with batch-file in different chrome profiles, if that's the problem, i can help you. Before asking a question here, i recommend doing a search on a search engine (like Google) or on YouTube. By doing some research i found a video that may help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLmTo_O3hjU (not uploaded by me) , anyways, **Here is the solution:**
your code is trying to open https://www.youtube.com with the the system's default broswer. To open that link with chrome's different profiles you need to change the code:

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" https://www.youtube.com --profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

So your code will be:

```
@ECHO OFF
START "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" https://www.youtube.com --profile-directory="Profile 1"
START "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" https://www.youtube.com --profile-directory="Profile 2"
PAUSE > NUL
EXIT
```

If it doesn't work, try changing the chrome path (i writed the usual default path) and tell me if it works. Hope i've been helpful, if not, leave a comment and i will try to re-edit the answer.

Comment: It still open the profile but not the link in the profile. 
Code I Used Is Below . . .


`START "https://www.youtube.com/" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2"`

Comment: try to invert the link and the app: `START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "www.youtube.com" --profile-directory="Profile 2"` does it work?

Comment: Tried a few variations not working

Comment: @DamDarBilla786 have you tried writing this instead:
`start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.youtube.com --profile-directory="Profile 1"`